# Как реализовать метод асинхронно,не используя async/await?

Tags: c#, async-await

```
private async void DoSomethibng() {
 var a = await  MAsync();
 Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

так как у вас метод async void, то можно его переделать так - будет почти то же самое.

```
private void DoSomethibng()
{
    MAsync().ContinueWith(t=>Console.WriteLine(t.Result));
}
```

Comment: А если не void,то как быть?

Comment: @Nikita `return MAsync().ContinueWith(t=>Console.WriteLine(t.Result));` или задавать второй вопрос с конкретными примерами кода.